# Mysqli_error throws a 404 error on x10Hosting and Hostinger, myth or truth?

Tags: php, mysqli, unity-game-engine, http-status-code-404, mysql-error-1064

Well, I have a serious problem, I can't see any error from mysqli, because x10hosting doesn't allow it...

I show some pics:

[image: no mysqli_error in code]
[image: mysqli_error throws the 404 error]

I'm trying to make a Login System in Unity, and well, where you can see what really happens when I make a request with *HttpWebRequest* and I try to get it with *HttpWebResponse*...

I run the script into localhost using XAMPP and everything worked perfectly..

A friend told me that this problem also happen in Hostinger... So, maybe it's a security restriction from the hosting?

Anyway, is there any alternative for see mysqli errors, or I have to guess why the error happen?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: You run it in XAMPP and it "works perfectly"?  What about that warning it's throwing on Line 93?

Comment: Well, it's shows the warning but doesn't throw a 404 I mean :P
This happened with other proyect, it wasn't this, I don't want to port everything back to localhost.. Because this is too much work :/

Comment: Well fix the error and see if you still get a 404.  If you don't, then maybe your friend is correct.  I'd be surprised if it's causing a 404, though.

Comment: Yep, I fix the query error and now everything works fine :/